# Review button in top bar isn't updating

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, moderation

Several times, I've seen that the review queue appears empty, but the top-bar icon indicates otherwise. For instance I'll vote on something, but the top-bar notifier doesn't update.

Is this by design, because its pretty unhelpful if I think "there's things to look at" and there aren't?

[image]

Comment: Have you checked in your list of skipped items?

Comment: @DrMayhem no, but I didn't even know I could... I see no such link on http://music.stackexchange.com/review

Answer (score 4):

The number shown in the brown box is the sum of the numbers of items in all queues that you can access. This includes the items you have already acted on. That is, if there are **3 suggested edits** and **2 close vote** items, the number **reads 5** to everybody who's got both **close** and **edit** privileges. It will read 3 to someone who's allowed to edit but not to close.

This is due to the fact that the number is cached per-site and not per-user. Despite very inconvenient, this is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

Comment: So the figures change when you're the last to make the decision stand, and that's why the numbers sometimes change after you reviewed an issue? Guess that's where the confusion is from, I've also wondered about this.

Comment: @MeaningfulUsername Exactly, if you're the one to resolve the review item, the number will change as soon as you hit F5.

Comment: Are you sure about this one? I thought the number at the top was only suggested edits - otherwise the number would constantly be 9kish on stack overflow. Suggested edits are a special case as they make a post 'locked' - so should be resolved asap.

Comment: Hold on...I retract the above! [Apparantly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/212225/233816) it changed about a year ago!